# How to save value on Readonly / editable false fields in odoo Models?

Tags: model, field, odoo, odoo-8

I've a field which I want to compute it's value on change, but I don't want the user can modify it.

If I set the field as readonly=1 or editable=0 the value isn't store.

I'm trying to set a global discount on the invoice

```
class account_invoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"

    global_discount_p = fields.Float('Descuento porcentaje')
    global_discount = fields.Float('Descuento')
    neto = fields.Float('Neto')

    @api.one
    @api.depends('invoice_line.price_subtotal', 'tax_line.amount','global_discount_p')
    def _compute_amount(self):
        ret = super(account_invoice,self)._compute_amount()
        if self.type == 'in_invoice':
            self.neto = self.amount_untaxed
            discount = self.global_discount_p/100
            self.global_discount = self.neto * discount
            self.amount_untaxed = self.neto - self.global_discount

            for line in self.tax_line:
                line.base = self.amount_untaxed
                line.amount = line.amount - (line.amount * discount)

            self.amount_tax = sum(line.amount for line in self.tax_line)
            self.amount_total = self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax

        return ret
```

And in the layout:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='amount_untaxed']" position="before">
                <field name="neto" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="global_discount_p" onchange="_compute_amount"/>
                <field name="global_discount" readonly="1"/>
            </xpath>
```

It work well, if I remove readonly="1" attrs from the fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining the fields as

```
neto = fields.Float('Neto', compute='_compute_amount', store=True)
global_discount = fields.Float('Descuento', compute='_compute_amount', store=True)
```

Answer (score 14):

In `odoo11` you can use `force_save="1"` in the xml file

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: force_save="1" is apply on readonly field so you will save this field it's working perfect thank you so much

Comment: Works on 12.0 as well, thanks!! Read more about this [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/3b3f6f0)

Comment: In 11.0, in a tree view (lines of an invoice) if you apply <attribute name="force_save">1</attribute> to invoice_line_ids, readonly="1" won't work (it disables editable="bottom" and the records are editable), but if you apply for each field in the tree view, it works. Solved my problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Override this two methods in your account_invoice class and declare field like,

```
global_discount = fields.Float('Descuento', readonly=True)



@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals['global_discount']:
        if vals['type'] == 'in_invoice':
        vals['neto'] = vals['amount_untaxed']
        discount = vals['global_discount_p']/100
        vals['global_discount'] = vals['neto'] * discount
        vals['amount_untaxed'] = vals['neto'] - vals['global_discount']

        for line in vals['tax_line']:
            line.base = vals['amount_untaxed']
            line.amount = line.amount - (line.amount * discount)

        vals['amount_tax'] = sum(line.amount for line in vals['tax_line'])
        vals['amount_total'] = vals['amount_untaxed'] + vals['amount_tax']
    res = super(PersonInformation, self).create(vals)
    return res

@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    if vals['global_discount']:
        if vals['type'] == 'in_invoice':
        vals['neto'] = vals['amount_untaxed']
        discount = vals['global_discount_p']/100
        vals['global_discount'] = vals['neto'] * discount
        vals['amount_untaxed'] = vals['neto'] - vals['global_discount']

        for line in vals['tax_line']:
            line.base = vals['amount_untaxed']
            line.amount = line.amount - (line.amount * discount)

        vals['amount_tax'] = sum(line.amount for line in vals['tax_line'])
        vals['amount_total'] = vals['amount_untaxed'] + vals['amount_tax']
    res = super(PersonInformation, self).create(vals)
    return res
```

And in the layout:

```
<field name="global_discount" readonly="1"/>
```

I hope this will help you.